# Difference between Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 cross tools vs MSVC++ redistributable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

To use intel fortran in windows environment with other commercial software package, pre-requisite is to have Microsoft Visual C++:
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 cross tools

If I check my installed programs, I see that "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 redistributable 10.0.40219"

Is "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 redistributable 10.0.40219" different from "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 cross tools"?

Over the web, I read that to have Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 cross tools, I need to install MS visual studio 2010.

Do I have to purchase MS visual studio to have "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 cross tools" ?

So I am confused !

Thanks in advance for your prompt response !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redistributables are just the libraries you are permitted to install to get msvc built applications to run on the client system.

It is not the same as having msvc 2010 installed on a system.

Things with different names are generally different things, even if part of the name is similar.